# I want to understand the recursive logic of the below program to determine how the output is calculated

Tags: python, recursion

Program

```
def fun(n):
    if n > 100:
        return n - 5
    return fun(fun(n+11))

print(fun(90))
```

Output is -

```
97
```

I want to know why the program got terminated when n was 102

Comment: You see the condition `if n > 100:`?

Comment: When the number is greater than 100 the program just returns a value, n this case, the first call returns 101 (greater than 100) and it returns some value (96), then when n is 102 it just has the return statement and the program has  to finish

Comment: The first thing, i would trying is, to take a paper and write down the steps. 
Each change of "n" or call of the function "fun". For the unterstanding it's easier .

Comment: when I tried to call the function fun(45), the output was 100. As per above explanation, when n was (101), it should have ended with output 96, because then it just has a return statement. But output was 100. Could you please provide any detail that I am missing out?

Comment: One useful approach for debugging recursive functions is to print input at the very beginning of the function call. You might want to add `print(n)` in the first line of the function to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I added the print statements to the method and knew what n was at each call. It's the exit logic that I am not able to fully understand.

Comment: Try drawing a computing flowchart. Helps a lot in drafting recursive logic and is pretty good habits when coding.

Comment: @shalabh when `n==102`, the recursive call is never reached and you get `102 - 5 == 97` returned from the first `if` statement, since `n > 100` is `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't state whether you were expecting a different result or you were just curious as to the outcome and why;

**Why for your example `fun(90)`**

The logic only returns fully from the function when `n` is greater than 100 during the ***second*** invocation of itself. If `n` is greater than 100 during invocation of `fun(n + 11)` it is only returning the result to the next recursion.

Here is the pseudo trace of your function:

```
In fun with 90                          <= Initial call
In fun with 101                         <= first 'inner' (n+11) call
In > 100 with 101 and returning 96      <= greater than 100 condition
In fun with 96                          <= second 'outer' call 
In fun with 107                         <= fall through as n < 100 to 'inner' (n+11) call
In > 100 with 107 and returning 102     <= greater than 100 condition
In fun with 102                         <= second 'outer' call
In > 100 with 102 and returning 97      <= greater than 100 condition
97
```